# httpd config for ip based virtual host

Tags: centos6, httpd

can i use an ip address for `ServerName` in virtualhost?
i have setup one similar but it is not resolving to site [I do not have a domain]

```
<VirtualHost 180.170.180.244>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev.example.com/
ServerName 180.170.180.244
ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
```

does it luks correct? 
i did not changed any other default values lik listen etc .
my purpose is to access my site using ip address only. [etc info: Centos 6, NAS with firewall ]

Thanks

Comment: Is your config causing issues? What is not working? - Please keep in mind that only questions about *professional* server administration are allowed, not you personal projects.

Comment: i asked this question on so and it was sugegsted to ask here. Yes i'm working on client's project and i'm not a server administrator, rather a developer. But question is simple: when i do not have a domain name can ip address be used as `servername` ? if not what is the workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the IP address for `ServerName` should not pose an issue.

When not using `NameVirtualHost`, it should be safe to pick any `ServerName` value or omit the setting inside the `VirtualHost` altogether.